# Adding nested php array to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following php array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => page_1
        [clicks] => 3
        [time] => 14250
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => page_2
        [clicks] => 1
        [time] => 123
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => page_3

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => page_4
        [clicks] => 2
        [time] => 1450
    )
```

)

and the following table:

```
tbl_usage
--------
page_1
page_2
page_3
page_4
```

What is the best way to add the 'clicks' and 'time' from the array to the proper page column - so the table looks like this:

```
page_1          page_2       page_3          page_4
--------        -------      ---------       ----------
3:14250         1:123        0:0             2:1450
```

Comment: Well, your table should have three columns (name, clicks and time), you save each entry ("array") as a row in there. Isn't that obvious?

Comment: Please explain your down votes so I can learn to use this site better. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = array(...); // your data array;
$values = array();
foreach ($data $v)
{
    $clicks = (int)$v['clicks'];
    $time   = (int)$v['time'];
    $values[$v['name']] = ($clicks > 0 ? $clicks : 0) . ':' . ($time > 0 ? $time : 0);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_usage` (`" . implode("`, `", array_keys($values)) . "`) VALUES ('" . implode("', '", $values) . "')";
```

But I think that you need rethink the structure of the table.

Comment: Great answer, works perfect. What do you mean about the structure of the table?  What is a better way?

Comment: The statistic of pages should be per row.